# Answer/Respond/Reply

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

**Finn's room.**

Finn takes his walkie-talkie and speaks into it --

Finn: *Joel? Joel, are you there?*

**Joel's room.**

Joel answers/responds/replies his walkie-talkie (1) --
Joel picks up his walkie-talkie and answers/responds/replies (2) --

Joel: *I'm here.*

**Questions:**

- Can I use 'answers', 'responds', and 'replies' in both sentence (1) and (2)?
- Which of them would be most common to use?

Answer (score -1):

Both *respond* and *reply* need to be followed by *to* if there is an object.

If Joel *responds to* the walkie-talkie, he does something as a result of hearing it.

He *replies to* Finn's question, not to the machine.

To *answer* the telephone (or a two-way radio) is probably the most common expression.